# Remove periods before the first comma in a string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

How can I remove the periods before the first comma in these strings?

```
 xx <- c("fefe.3. fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw", 
          "fefe3. fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw",
          "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw")
```

Desired output:

```
    "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw"
    "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw"
    "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw"
```

I've started with `gsub("\\.","", xx))`, which removes all periods. How to change it to specify 'only the period before the first comma'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like this is cheating, but it works for this simple example....

```
xx <- c("fefe.3. fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw", 
        "fefe3. fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw",
        "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw")

temp <- strsplit(xx, ",")

sapply(seq_along(temp), function(x) {
  t1 <- gsub("\\.", "", temp[[x]][1])
  paste(t1, temp[[x]][2], temp[[x]][-c(1, 2)], sep = ",")
})
# [1] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw"  "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw" 
# [3] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw"
```

The basic idea above is that since you're only going to be looking for a period in the first chunk before a comma, why not split it and use a basic `gsub` on that, and then put the pieces back together. Unlikely to be efficient....

Comment: Thanks very much! That does the job on my actual use-case also. I thought there might be a solution with less characters (I'm a lazy typist), but this has got me on the way and that's all that matters in this case. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ben, I'm sure there is, but sometimes thinking too much about regular expressions gives me brain-freeze. :)

Comment: heh! I know exactly what you mean. I am a complete regex-idiot.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
gsub("\\.(.*,.*)","\\1", xx)
[1] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw" 
[2] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw" 
[3] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw"
```

The regex works like this:

- `\\.` looks for a period
- `(.*,.*)` looks for a comma inside other text, and groups it
- `\\1` refers to the first group

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I appreciate that. With your line I still get one period in the first item: `"fefe3. fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw"` (you might have got an early edit of my Q when the example data were a bit different, sorry for the confusion!)

Comment: @Ben, you could just nest Andrie's `gsub` here and get your answer too:  `gsub("\\.(.*,.*)", "\\1", gsub("\\.(.*,.*)", "\\1", xx))`. This depends on your knowing how many periods you can expect before your first comma, or on your skills at writing recursive functions....

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thanks, I don't know how many periods to expect and I'm not there yet in terms of writing recursive functions...

Answer (score 1):

This uses `gsubfn` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) to extract the longest substring starting at the beginning of the string and containing no commas. (This would be the entire string if there were no commas in it).  It then uses `gsub` to remove the periods within that.  (If it were desired to only remove the first period within the substring then change the `gsub` to `sub`.)

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("^[^,]*", ~ gsub("\\.", "", x), xx)
```

The result is:

```
[1] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw" 
[2] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw" 
[3] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw"
```

Comment: Thanks, that `gsubfn` is intriguing!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about speed or amount of typing but here's an approach using qdap's `beg2char` and `char2end` functions:

```
## xx <- c("fefe.3. fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw", 
##     "fefe3. fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw",
##     "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw")

library(qdap)

paste0(gsub("\\.", "", beg2char(xx, ",")), char2end(xx, ",", include=TRUE))

## > paste0(gsub("\\.", "", beg2char(xx, ",")), char2end(xx, ",", include=TRUE))
## [1] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw"  "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. trgw" 
## [3] "fefe3 fregg, ff, 34.gr. tr.gw"
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is definitely the easiest for me to understand.